# Picturebox absorbing the form's background color

Tags: c#, image, winforms, controls, transparency

I'm creating a chess game but I have a problem http://prntscr.com/ayaluj as you can see the pieces absorb the form's background the board is being created during the runtime it's just bunch of `Picturebox` with edited `BackColor` property. The pieces are also `Picturebox` if it matters the images them self's are in *.png* format and have a transparent background, also the `Picturebox` that hold's them has a transparent `BackColor`, how can I remove this colour absorbing ? The form is double buffered too. I've tried various methods recommended here on SO like implementing my own picturebox and overriding the paint on background event however this changes nothing .. The pieces pictureboxs parent controls is the form itself.

Comment: Of course the pieces should not have a transparent backcolr bur the color of the field they are on if those fields are separate boxes, which is a bad idea especially when you want to move them over the border between fields.. Better: Draw those fields on a common board control and nest the pieces in the board! Since the is no tranparency for overlapping controls, this is pretty much the only way. Unless you want to draw the background on every move..

Comment: What happens if they are in between 2 fields ? They are being moved with a dragging move so they cant be put on in between 2 fields but they can be  there for a few seconds while dragging them

Comment: Indeed. See my updated comment

Comment: I'm afraid I'm not sure what's common board control. Do you mean 1 big panel and but all the pictureboxs in ?

Comment: Yes. One big Control, maybe a Picturebox. Draw 32 squares in the Paint event or pick a nice board image. Then __nest__ each piece in it: `piece01.Parent = yourBoard;`...  Note that at least for a PictureBox you need to do this in code, not the Designer! If you pick a Panel, use a doublebuffered subclass. (The Form's doublebuffered will not help any other control.)

Comment: The form's double buffer is removing the flickering effect when dragging control combined with the `Refresh()` method. I'm currently implementing the "Big control" idea I will let you know if it works.

Comment: Nothing changed all the 64 tile pictureboxes were added to the controls of the "Big" picturebox and also the figures were added there. Am I doing something wrong ?

Comment: Indeed. Do not use any pictureboxes for the fields! The fields should be __drawn or__ be part of a background image that shows a chaessboard. Use only 16 PictureBoxes for the __pieces__! __They__ need to be children to the board. Then tranparency will work.. So all together you have __17__ controls: One board and 16 pieces.. When the fields are controls, transparency will only work __within__ but you want the pices to __overlap__ the fields during the moving..

Comment: I'm really sorry than I cant move this to a chat but I guess I will just keep replying here, so I really cant do that because my main logic combines them both. A figure class and a picturebox that show's the image. So i use those pictureboxs to detect where on the board a piece currently is.

Comment: Well that is a fine design; just exchange the reference to the PBox with a reference to or adress of a field. While you're at it: I guess a fields class won't be too much; always better one more class than one too few. - The transparency issue really can't be overcome with your original design.

Comment: Again I'm sorry that we are extending this but I'm a beginner and I'm not sure what is address of a field

Comment: Well that is up to your design. The most direct could be strings: "A1".."H8" but a field class would more likely have properties for row and column number..